# Efficient method of finding all maximum cliques of a graph in GAP

Tags: performance, graph-theory, clique, clique-problem, gap-system

I wish to find all maximum cliques of special types of Cayley graphs called derangement graphs. I work in GAP and I currently use the GRAPE package to establish the following:

```
#This is a nice example to work with.
grp := PrimitiveGroup(8,2);
n := LargestMovedPoint(grp);

#The derangement graph of grp
derang := [];
for x in grp do 
    if NrMovedPoints(x) = n then
        AddSet(derang, x);
    fi;
od;

#This uses the GRAPE package.
Cay:=CayleyGraph(grp, derang);

#The following function returns a set of complete subgraphs of Cay (of size n) which are maximal.
#The cliques are returned as vertices of Cay.
max_clique_indices := CompleteSubgraphs(Cay,n,1);

#We convert the vertices of Cay into permutations of grp.
max_clique_perms := [];
for x in max_clique_indices do
    Add(max_clique_perms, Cay.names{x});
od;

#To find all maximum cliques, we perform the following "right translation" action.
#This is where the inefficiency is (I think). We get so many duplicates that must be removed.
maximum_cliques := [];
for x in grp do
    for cl in max_clique_perms do
        Add(maximum_cliques, x*cl);
    od;
od;

maximum_cliques := AsSet(List(maximum_cliques, AsSet));
```

I've read the the GRAPE documentation many times, but I can't find a command that generates all maximum cliques. In Sage, one can invoke the cliquer command (https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/graphs/sage/graphs/cliquer.html), which finds all maximum cliques fairly quickly and efficiently (for groups of order < 3000 in my experience). Is there such an option in GAP?

Note: I tried using the YAGS package as well to make use of the "CompletesOfGivenOrder(Cay,n)" command, but I found it to be incredibly slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several remarks:

- To "find all *maximum* cliques" (i.e. cliques with the largest possible size) you can ask Grape to compute (G-orbit representatives of) all *maximal* cliques, then pick among those the one which have maximum size
- Your test program runs in a few milliseconds for me, so any optimizations I can provide are hypothetical; it would be good to know which inputs you have that don't complete in just a few milliseconds?
- For the sake of testing, I tried `PrimitiveGroup(15,2)`; there the first bottleneck was to find the maximal cliques (which took 10 seconds in that example). This can be overcome by using the `digraphs` package (which only took 200 milliseconds). But whether this is suitable for your case or not depends on the actual inputs you are interested in.
- Grape by default only returns representatives for the G-orbits of cliques; and for many problems in Cayley graphs, it is sufficient to work with these. As you don't say what you want to do with these cliques, I can't say whether there is such an approach in your case, but I'd suggest that you ponder the possibility, as that will (if possible) by far the most efficient way to go about it
- The bit you identified as inefficient is basically performing an orbit enumeration, but indeed in a very inefficient way. To overcome this, just use GAP's rich orbit functionality to resolve this.

Here is a modified version of your program which computes all maximum cliques. It runs in a few milliseconds on my computer, but of course for larger inputs gets much slower.

```
LoadPackage("grape");

grp := PrimitiveGroup(8,2);
n := LargestMovedPoint(grp);

# the derangement graph of grp; this uses the GRAPE package
Cay := CayleyGraph(grp, Filtered(grp, x -> NrMovedPoints(x) = n));

# compute a set of maximal cliques in Cay which is guaranteed to contain
# at least one representative from each orbit of maximal cliques;
# returned as lists of indices into Cay
max_clique_indices := CompleteSubgraphs(Cay,-1,1);

# compute the size of maximum clique
msize := Maximum(List(max_clique_indices, Length));

# discard all cliques which are not maximum
max_clique_indices:=Filtered(max_clique_indices, c -> Length(c) = msize);

# convert the vertices of Cay into permutations of grp.
max_clique_perms := List(max_clique_indices, i->AsSet(Cay.names{i}));

# we want all maximum cliques, so compute the orbits of the orbit representatives;
# we act on sets by right multiplication
maximum_clique_orbs := Orbits(grp, max_clique_perms, {set,perm} -> AsSet(set*perm));

# finally merge all the orbits into one
maximum_cliques := Concatenation(maximum_clique_orbs);
```

You could also try Digraphs; compute Cay as above, but then proceed like this:

```
LoadPackage("digraph");
dig:=Digraph(Cay);
max_clique_indices := DigraphMaximalCliquesReps(dig);
msize := Maximum(List(max_clique_indices, Length));
max_clique_indices:=Filtered(max_clique_indices, c -> Length(c) = msize);
maximum_clique_orbs := Orbits(AutomorphismGroup(dig), max_clique_indices, OnSets);
maximum_cliques := List(Union(maximum_clique_orbs), i->AsSet(Cay.names{i}));
```

Comment: Excellent response! I never could figure out GAP's "Orbits" function from the documentation. I'm still a bit unsure: when you define "maximum_clique_orbs" we have {set, perm}; is set an element of grp and perm an element of max_clique_perms? I'm currently benchmarking both new methods with my old method - already the new methods are way faster and less RAM intensive. In order of easier to hardest, the PrimitiveGroup(n,k) I'm using to test are: (8,2), (16,15), (16,13), and (16,14). The last one is very hard with my original method - yours is a huge improvement!

Comment: The notation `{a,b}->...` is shorthand for `function(a,b) return ...; end`; and here this function is used to define a (right) action, as explained in the chapter 41 "Group Actions"; that is, the second (right) argument is an element of the acting group, and we are interested in the image of the first argument under the action of the second